# Pushing an object onto an array, manipulation changes every element

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

In JavaScript I have an array. I'm using `push()` to add array elements, but when I manipulate said elements, each array element is changed, when only one should be. My code is:

```
// Arrays to hold the elements that have been created (added to the document).
create.element_array                       = []
create.element_array["name"]               = []
create.element_array["name"]["properties"] = []

var element_properties = 
{
    // Default all to 0.
    borderTopStyle: 0, borderRightStyle: 0, borderBottomStyle: 0, borderLeftStyle: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, 
    borderTopColor: 0, borderRightColor: 0, borderBottomColor: 0, borderLeftColor: 0,
}

// Testing purposes. These will be added dynamically in production version.
create.element_array["name"].push("default_header");
create.element_array["name"]["properties"].push(element_properties);

create.element_array["name"].push("default_body");
create.element_array["name"]["properties"].push(element_properties);

create.element_array["name"].push("default_footer");
create.element_array["name"]["properties"].push(element_properties);

// Evidence that each array element is changed with index manipulation.
create.element_array["name"]["properties"][0].borderTopStyle = "dashed";

console.log(create.element_array["name"]["properties"][0]);
console.log(create.element_array["name"]["properties"][1]);
console.log(create.element_array["name"]["properties"][2]);
```

The result I expect from this is that ONLY index 0 should be changed, but this is not the case. The above console.log lines will output the following:

```
Object
borderBottomColor: 0
borderBottomStyle: 0
borderBottomWidth: 0
borderLeftColor: 0
borderLeftStyle: 0
borderLeftWidth: 0
borderRightColor: 0
borderRightStyle: 0
borderRightWidth: 0
borderTopColor: 0
borderTopStyle: "dashed"
borderTopWidth: 0
__proto__: Object
 library.js:8
Object
borderBottomColor: 0
borderBottomStyle: 0
borderBottomWidth: 0
borderLeftColor: 0
borderLeftStyle: 0
borderLeftWidth: 0
borderRightColor: 0
borderRightStyle: 0
borderRightWidth: 0
borderTopColor: 0
borderTopStyle: "dashed"
borderTopWidth: 0
__proto__: Object
 library.js:8
Object
borderBottomColor: 0
borderBottomStyle: 0
borderBottomWidth: 0
borderLeftColor: 0
borderLeftStyle: 0
borderLeftWidth: 0
borderRightColor: 0
borderRightStyle: 0
borderRightWidth: 0
borderTopColor: 0
borderTopStyle: "dashed"
borderTopWidth: 0
__proto__: Object
 library.js:8
```

Why is `borderTopStyle` being changed for every element, when I explicitly define index 0 to be the only index that gets changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same reference to the `element_properties` object to each spot in the array. This means that when you try to change it, you're changing the value of the object pointed-to by that reference.

You might want to instead use a constructor the properties object:

```
function ElementProperties(){
}
ElementProperties.prototype = {
    // Default all to 0.
    borderTopStyle: 0, borderRightStyle: 0, borderBottomStyle: 0, borderLeftStyle: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, 
    borderTopColor: 0, borderRightColor: 0, borderBottomColor: 0, borderLeftColor: 0,
};
```

Then, something like this:

```
create.element_array["name"].push("default_header");
create.element_array["name"]["properties"].push(new ElementProperties());
```

Comment: Thanks. This was most convenient and easiest to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are passed by reference in javascript. Quite literally:

element_properties == create.element_array["name"]["properties"][0] == create.element_array["name"]["properties"][1]

You can remedy this using the new operator, or using different object literals.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new instances of the element_properties object. Like so:

```
var properties_el = Object.create( element_properties );

create.element_array["name"].push("default_header");
create.element_array["name"]["properties"].push( properties_el);
```

At the moment you are inserting the same object 3 times. Another option would be to use an object to store your properties like so:

```
create.element_object = {};
create.element_object["name"] = properties_el;
```

This allows you to access properties in the following way

```
create.element_object["name"]["borderTopStyle"]
```

or

```
create.element_object.name.borderTopStyle
```

Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the more efficient method of property access, I will be implementing this into the code.